# R finding row sums in between rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Type  Value
 0     0
 0     0
 1     0
 2     50
 2     20
 0     0
 2     20
 2     10
 1     0
```

I am looking to summarize it as follows

```
Type  Value
 0     0
 0     0
 1     0
 0     70
 1     30
```

Basically in between either a 0 or 1 in Type, I am looking to summarize the value of all Type ==2 and paste it in the subsequent 0 or 1 that appears.
Any pointers on how I can achieve this?
I tried the aggregate but it sums all the values based on column name.
Thanks!
Edit:
Pattern of summing: Basically I need to sum all the values of Type 2 in between Type 0 or 1.

Comment: I'm not getting the pattern of summing. Can you be explicit as to how the calculation works?

Comment: yes, your desired output seems to be inconsistent - once you have a Type 0 with Value 70, then a Type 1 with Value 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to do this with `data.table` or similar packages. Try this

```
library(data.table)  #data.table 1.9.8
setDT(dat)
# Generate a consecutive grouping variable on the basis of a cumulative
# count of values that are *not* equal to 2. This has to be done in reverse
# so the right cases are grouped together.
dat[,grp := rev(cumsum(rev(Type!=2)))]

#   Type Value grp
#1:    0     0   5
#2:    0     0   4
#3:    1     0   3
#4:    2    50   2
#5:    2    20   2
#6:    0     0   2
#7:    2    20   1
#8:    2    10   1
#9:    1     0   1

# Then take the last Type in each group, along with the sum of Value 
dat[, .(Type=last(Type), Value=sum(Value)), by=grp][,-1]

#   Type Value
#1:    0     0
#2:    0     0
#3:    1     0
#4:    0    70
#5:    1    30
```

Where dat was:

```
dat <- structure(list(Type = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
    Value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 20L, 0L, 20L, 10L, 0L)), .Names = c("Type", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```